# How to run/debug WatchOS apps using AppCode?

Tags: ios, watchos-2, appcode

How to run/debug WatchOS apps using AppCode?
I just imported an XCode project into AppCode - there's no way to run the watch simulator (there are options for the main app though). What am I missing?